# Multiple Materialized view refresh via pg_cron blocks other scheduled cron jobs

Tags: database, postgresql, cron, pg-cron

I have a table "T1".

2 materialized views MV1 and MV2  built on T1.

The materialized views have aggregate functions on the data.

Using pg_cron, I scheduled view refresh (concurrent) at 5 min, 15 min and 12 hours for MV1, MV2 and MV3 respectively.The view refresh for MV1 takes time more than 5 min, for example 25 min.

When MV1 refresh is in progress, i expect the 15th min refresh job for MV2 to start as all are independent views.
But if one cron job is in progress, none of the other cron jobs start.

Tried with a dummy cron job , to run every one minute. The dummy job also does not run if any other cron is in progress.
What could be the reason and how to solve it?

postgres version 14

pg cron version 14

But if i manually run a refresh materialized view concurrently on MV2 then it works.